# Multiple .NET Applications Share Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have 2 mvc .net applications, 1 is written in vb and the other in c#.

The are structured as follows:

- http://app1.example.com, (c#)
- http://app1.example.com/site (vb)

The user initially logs into the /site app and has the ability to navigate to the root site.

My web.config application > authentication is as follows:

```
<forms 
name="SITECOOKIE" 
protection="All"  
path="/" 
domain="app1.example.com" 
timeout="15" />
```

My issue is, the user logs into the http://app1.example.com/ site app where the Login controller takes care of the authentication process and sets the "SITECOOKIE". However, when navigating to the root site, http://app1.example.com, the root app cannot access or see the cookie "SITECOOKIE".

What can I do so the root app has access to the cookie "SITECOOKIE"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set domain to `example.com`, if you want to share cookie between two websites.

```
<forms 
   name="SITECOOKIE" 
   protection="All"  
   path="/" 
   domain="example.com" 
   timeout="15" />
```

Ensure you set same ***machinekey*** in both web.config file.